# Using PolygonAnnotation to draw within a chart

Tags: c#, charts, mschart

I'm trying to use PolygonAnnotation to draw a Polygon within a chart where I have four points that i would like to use as vertex.

Below my chart

[image]
[chart1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfk0d.png)

These Points are set at runtime in a Bubble Series:

```
System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series serieSA = chartCartesian.Series.FindByName("SeriesSafetyArea");

DataPoint dpA = new DataPoint(radarConfigured.SafetyArea.PointA.X,new Double[]{radarConfigured.SafetyArea.PointA.Y, -20});
DataPoint dpB = new DataPoint(radarConfigured.SafetyArea.PointB.X, new Double[]{radarConfigured.SafetyArea.PointB.Y, -20});
DataPoint dpC = new DataPoint(radarConfigured.SafetyArea.PointC.X, new Double[] { radarConfigured.SafetyArea.PointC.Y, -20 });
DataPoint dpD = new DataPoint(radarConfigured.SafetyArea.PointD.X, new Double[] { radarConfigured.SafetyArea.PointD.Y, -20 });
                dpA.Label = "A";
                dpB.Label = "B";
                dpC.Label = "C";
                dpD.Label = "D";
                serieSA.Points.Add(dpA);
                serieSA.Points.Add(dpB);
                serieSA.Points.Add(dpC);
                serieSA.Points.Add(dpD);
```

I would like to obtain a figure like a rectangle using these points.
i've tried usign this code:

```
safetyAreaAnnotation = new PolygonAnnotation();
            safetyAreaAnnotation.ClipToChartArea = chartCartesian.ChartAreas[0].Name;
            //safetyAreaAnnotation.AnchorX = 10;
            //safetyAreaAnnotation.AnchorY = 20;
            PointF[] points = new PointF[4];
            points[0].X = (float)dpA.XValue;
            points[0].Y = (float)dpA.YValues[0] ;
            points[1].X = (float)dpB.XValue;
            points[1].Y = (float)dpB.YValues[0];
            points[2].X = (float)dpC.XValue;
            points[2].Y = (float)dpC.YValues[0];
            points[3].X = (float)dpD.XValue;
            points[3].Y = (float)dpD.YValues[0];
            byte[] type = new byte[4];
            type[0] = (byte)PathPointType.Start;
            type[1] = (byte)PathPointType.Line;
            type[2] = (byte)PathPointType.Line;
            type[3] = (byte)PathPointType.CloseSubpath;

            safetyAreaAnnotation.GraphicsPath=new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath(points,type);  
           // //safetyAreaAnnotation.IsSizeAlwaysRelative = false;
           // //safetyAreaAnnotation.BackColor = Color.Red;
           safetyAreaAnnotation.AxisX = chartCartesian.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
           safetyAreaAnnotation.AxisY = chartCartesian.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;
           safetyAreaAnnotation.AnchorDataPoint = serieSA.Points[0];
           // //safetyAreaAnnotation.AnchorX = 1;
           // //safetyAreaAnnotation.AnchorY = 20;
            chartCartesian.Annotations.Add(safetyAreaAnnotation);
```

But it doesn't work. Nothing is displayed in my chart.
Maybe I should use something different to draw this polygon?

**Update**

That is the result after drawing a polygon:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1 - Annotation

Your Annotation doesn't show because you didn't set a size for it.

From [MSDN on PolyLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.polylineannotation.graphicspath%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> Remarks
>
> A polyline must use coordinates relative to an annotation object,
>   where (0,0) denotes the top-left coordinates and (100,100) denotes the
>   bottom-right coordinates of the annotation.

So the first thing you would need to do is the give the `Annotation` a `Size`:

```
safetyAreaAnnotation.Width = 10;
safetyAreaAnnotation.Height = 10;
```

This makes it rather big, as the `Size` is given in percent of the `ChartArea`..

For more see [MSDN on Height etc..](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.annotation.height%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

But even if you find a **suitable** size it is rather hard to set the polyline coordinates from `DataPoint` values to those **relative** to the `Annotation` area..

**Not recommended!**

---

### 2 - Drawing

**You can draw** onto the `Chart` in the `Pre- or PostPaint` events:

```
    ChartArea ca = chartCartesian.ChartAreas[0];
    Axis ax = ca.AxisX;
    Axis ay = ca.AxisY;

    List<DataPoint> dp = new List<DataPoint>() { dpA, dpB, dpC, dpD };
    List<PointF> points = dp.Select(x=> new PointF(
        (float)ax.ValueToPixelPosition(x.XValue), 
        (float)ay.ValueToPixelPosition(x.YValues[0])
        )).ToList();
    using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(64, Color.Gold)))
       e.ChartGraphics.Graphics.FillPolygon(brush, points.ToArray());
```

Just make sure the code has access to the `DataPoints`.

As you see this is rather simple: It makes use of the `ValueToPixelPosition` methods of the `Axes`.

This is directly relating to the `DataPoints`, so it will automatically scale & move when resizing.  **I highly recommend drawing the area** over using an the `Annotation`.

[image][image]

---

By the way: Your way to add a polygon to a `GraphicsPath` is overcomplicated. `AddPolygon(PointList.ToArray())` would have have worked just as well. Only when you want a **complex mix of rounded and pointed corners** would you actually go into setting the `Types` array..

Comment: Thank you very much. I've used your "drawing" solution and it works very well for what i have to do.

Comment: Nice result! - If you are happy with the answer, please consider consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it..! - I see that you have never done this: Go the the (invisible) checkmark at the top left, below the votes of the answer and click it! It turns green and gains us both a little reputation..